# how to convert EditText control's value in to float value in android

Tags: android, string, floating-point

im receiving some value from  EditText control. and i want that value for some calculation so i need to convert it to float value how can i do that?

i tried below But getting null pointer exception:

```
float ip1=Integer.getInteger(t1.getText().toString());
```

Any Soln?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String str = t1.getText().toString();
Float ip1 = new Float(str);
System.out.println("Float value = "+ip1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
float ip1=new Float(t1.getText().toString());
```